# SwiftUI - ScrollView & GeometryReader Pagination Bug - @State variable does not change value

Tags: pagination, uiscrollview, swiftui, geometryreader

so I've implemented pagination to some extent, however, there is a bug. I can only seem to execute  `self.searchViewModel.loadMoreData()` once, and that's only when the view has been presented.

This is my full-code:

```
@State var time = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .tracking).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(SYSTEM_BACKGROUND_COLOUR)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading)  {
                            if !self.searchViewModel.isLoading {
                                VStack {
                                    ForEach(self.searchViewModel.post, id: \.postID) { post in
                                        VStack {
                                            HeaderCell(post: post)
                                            FooterCell(post: post)
                                                .onAppear {
                                                    self.time = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .tracking).autoconnect()
                                                    
                                            }
                                            .onReceive( self.searchViewModel.time) { (_) in
                                                if geometry.frame(in: .global).maxY < UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 80{
                                                    print("Getting data")
                                                    self.searchViewModel.loadMoreData()
                                                    self.time.upstream.connect().cancel()
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Results"), displayMode: .inline)
}
```

I really believe it's because `time` isn't changing it's state. As the console only prints "Getting data" once. Once I scroll to the end of my view, after the next group of data has been collected and presented, nothing happens. I've been trying to sort this for hours.
I have read about how `@Binding` is much better to use, but I get constant errors whenever I try to implement it.

In essence, I just want to detect when the user has scrolled all the way to the bottom of my `ScrollView` so that I can call the function to get the next batch of information. I've tried almost every solution possible but no luck. I've shifted and changed both the `onAppear` & `onReceived` methods everywhere within my view.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This approach will not work, because ScrollView loads/renders all provided content at once at creation time. That's why you see print out only once.

Comment: @Asperi so would my best option be? Add a button saying `Load More`?

Comment: Something like https://www.donnywals.com/implementing-an-infinite-scrolling-list-with-swiftui-and-combine/